# I want to know about the plugins that help in while I write code on my Page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I want to know about the plugins that help me to write the coded blocks. I have tried out two or three but I am not able to know how to get along and put it to use. Please suggest me some good plugins and also how to use it if I need to represent some codes. Yeah I have many different languages that I code in... so the highlighting and other stuffs does matter. Please help.

Comment: I can't exactly tell what you're trying to accomplish. Can you be more specific? Are you looking for a syntax highlighter for inside your posts?

Comment: I am looking for a syntax highlighter. To represent my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience, I've found **[SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)** to be the best:

You put your code inside a shortcode and specify the language:

```
[sourcecode language='php']
//Displays the php code
[/sourcecode]


[sourcecode language='html']
<!-- Displays the html code-->
[/sourcecode]
```